# Rotate image left using swipe left in Jquery or Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I done my almost some functionality In my app .I done animation on  **tabhold** and **vmouseup** on removing the mouse.But I need to shift only one image at one time left and right while using swipeleft or swipe right.But my image rotate only in right not in left side.
Can you please tell me how to rotate image.
Link findle:http://jsfiddle.net/PMrDn/101/

```
$(document).off('swipeleft').on('swipeleft', '#index', function(event){    
        timerObject.interval_id = setInterval(animate, 20);
    });

    $(document).off('swiperight').on('swiperight', '#index', function(event){   
        timerObject.interval_id = setInterval(animate, 20);           
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling animate() for both cases, but animate() only rotates to the right (`boxes[idx].currentAngle--;`). You could pass the angle difference to animate() instead of always subtracting 1. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PMrDn/102/

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same function (animate) when swiping left or right. You can use a different function for each functionality or you can pass some parameters to specify left or right turning.

If you change 
`boxes[idx].currentAngle--;`

to 
`boxes[idx].currentAngle++;`

the items turn left

Comment: Yes you right but can you suggest me any good method ?for swiping left .or do some changes on fiddle